# How do I set up the TP-Link Ac 1200

Tags: networking, wireless

cannot connect to the internet at all through this usb dongle

Model: Archer T4U ver:1.0
I do not have any other way of connecting to the internet so I will have to transfer any downloads by usb drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need internet connection :

Install the `linux-headers` and `build-essential` then run:

```
git clone https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux.git
cd rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/
```

save and install the driver:

```
make
sudo make install
```

The newest version can be found [here](https://github.com/diederikdehaas/rtl8812AU) , you can compile it without editing files , recommanded by [@heynnema](https://askubuntu.com/users/4272/heynnema)

edit: original repo no longer requires editing.  see [abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/.../usb_intf.c](https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/blob/8db81745a218e867ae980fee406a8148767809ca/os_dep/linux/usb_intf.c#L299)

Comment: A newer driver that already includes support for your dongle can be found at `https://github.com/diederikdehaas/rtl8812AU`, and you can `git clone https://github.com/diederikdehaas/rtl8812AU.git`.